# Laravel 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to implement a like system but I do not know how to send a request to the like controller once the user hits the like button which is an a-tag. I created a new controller named LikeController due to ArticleController already having a POST method which is store.

Here is the PHP code for the controller

```php
use App\Article;
use App\Like;
use App\Events\NewLike;

class LikeController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $id = $request['id'];
      $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
      $user_id = $request->user()->id;
      $like = Like::where(['likeable_id' => $article->id, 'user_id' => $user_id]);
      $like_type = $possibleLike->like_type;

      // check if article exists

      if(!$like) {
          $like = new Like([
              'user_id' => $user_id,
              'like_type' => 'like',
              'likeable_id' => $article->id,
              'likeable_type' => 'article'
          ]);
      } else {
          if($like->like_type == 'like') {
              $like->like_type == 'dislike';
          } else if($like->like_type == 'dislike') {
              $like->like_type == 'like';
          }
      }
      $like->save();

      event(new NewLike($like));


      return redirect('/articles'.$article->id);
  }
}
```

Here is my Javascript in the vue component to get initiate the request:

```php
export default {
  props: ['articleId'],
  methods: {
    activateLike (articleId) {
      axios({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/likes',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
        },
        id: articleId
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If anyone needs more information, I'll post it below here.

---

Routes:

```php
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/leaderboard', 'PagesController@leaderboard');

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
Route::get('article/{category}', 'ArticlesController@display');

Route::post('/likes', 'LikeController@store');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: please include the routes

Comment: Hussein is right, **Method Not Allowed** occurs when you hit a route with the wrong http verb (e.g. route for `get` but you sent `post` instead). in case your route is correct already, try to `php artisan route:clear` to clear the routing cache.

Comment: Added routes to the post. @Hussein

Comment: also if that didn't work, try to remove trailing slash like so `url: 'likes'`, if that didn't work too, check in the network tab to see if the url is correct

Comment: URl is correct. It's hitting localhost:8000/likes

Comment: just see where your page leads you without ajax. or head over to the url specified in the ajax error (if any) and see what's holding you back. :p

Comment: It says MethodNotAllowedHTTPException